# What is a regular expression (regex) for matching words that DO NOT follow the "i before e except after c" rule?

Tags: regex

For words that do match the rule, I'm using:

```
\b\w*(cei|\bie|(?!c)\w(?=ie))\w*\b
```

But what about words that DO NOT match the popular rule, such as "science" or even "foreign?"

Comment: `\b\w*(?:cie|(?<!c)ei)\w*\b`?

Comment: If you are trying to correct spelling errors automatically, you have chosen the wrong tool.

Comment: I think `\b\w*(?:cie|(?<!c)ei)\w*\b` would work, but I'm using it within JavaScript, which does not support lookbacks.

Is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answering the question you asked

You were almost there! I tweaked your existing version [to work without lookbehinds](https://regex101.com/r/G8p7nx/1):

```
 \b\w*(?:cie|\bei|(?!c)\wei)\w*\b
```

The difference is that `\bei|(?!c)\wei` is looking for a non-c `\w` followed by "ie", or `\b` followed by "ie" (to match words like "either"). The lookbehind version finds the same things, but instead by looking for "ie"s *not preceded* by a c.

You can look at your problem as "words matching the rule 'e before i, except after c'", and then it's obvious that you can take your "i before e" solution and just flip the i's and e's, which is basically exactly what I did.

#### Answering the question you didn't ask, but which is more interesting

Your "solved problem" (the regex that *does* fit the rule) doesn't really work for all cases. The word "eighties", for instance, does contain "tie", which is an i before e after a non-c, so your regex does match it. But it also starts with "ei", which is an e before i not after c. So we need stricter rules for what *does* follow the rule:

1. a) Starts with "ie" OR b) Contains "cei" OR c) Contains an "ie" that follows a non-c `\w`.
2. a) Does not start with "ei" AND b) Does not contain "cie" AND c) Does not contain an "ei" that follows a non-c `\w`.

This is actually a pretty fun problem; I suspect there are several ways of solving it, some of which I haven't come up with yet and may be better. Still, [here is my solution](https://regex101.com/r/ZMvNxA/3) to "words that follow the rule":

```
\b(?!ei)((\w(?!ie|ei))*(cei|((?!c)\w|\b)ie))+(\w(?!ie|ei))*\b
```

Breaking down the logic behind it:

```
\b(?!ei)                 # guarantee 2.a
(
  (\w(?!ie|ei))*         # consume as many \w not followed by ie or ei as possible
  (cei|((?!c)\w|\b)ie)   # 1.b or 1.c or 1.a (exclusively: none of 2.)
)+                       # guarantee at least 1 match of 1.
(\w(?!ie|ei))*\b         # any trailing \w after the last match of 1. can't match 2.
```

Other notes:

1. Yup, that's nesting repetition. Should not cause catastrophic backtracking since both parts are mutually exclusive: `(\w(?!ie|ei))` can't start a match for `(cei|((?!c)\w|\b)ie)`.
2. I'm **making an assumption** that the sequence "ieei" won't appear; my solution matches it when it strictly shouldn't, but this sequence doesn't appear in my computer's dictionary so I'll consider it an edge case to chew on later.
3. As with your example, this will only work for all-lowercase c, e, and i. If you're only looking at lowercase strings, `\w` might not be the way to go; consider `[a-z]`.